# Change colour indicator in SlidingTabLayout

Tags: android

I wish to ask that is it possible to change the colour of the tab indicator in the SlidingTablayout? Must I use SlidingTabsColors from developer.android.com? I just want to change another colour instead of the default blue(I think) colour. Please advise. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 14):

Just to make it more clear.

```
SlidingTabLayout tabs = (SlidingTabLayout) findViewById(R.id.sliding_tabs); //referring the layout in xml file
tabs.setViewPager(viewpager);    //setting the viewpager


//setting indicator and divider color
tabs.setCustomTabColorizer(new SlidingTabLayout.TabColorizer() {

    @Override
    public int getIndicatorColor(int position) {
    return getResources().getColor(R.color.white);    //define any color in xml resources and set it here, I have used white
    }

    @Override
    public int getDividerColor(int position) {
    return getResources().getColor(R.color.white);
    }
});
```

Comment: how to set the color of the unselected tab INDICATOR

Answer (score 2):

As you can see in source code you must implement below interface

```
/**
 * Allows complete control over the colors drawn in the tab layout. Set with
 * {@link #setCustomTabColorizer(TabColorizer)}.
 */
public interface TabColorizer {

    /**
     * @return return the color of the indicator used when {@code position} is selected.
     */
    int getIndicatorColor(int position);

    /**
     * @return return the color of the divider drawn to the right of {@code position}.
     */
    int getDividerColor(int position);

}
```

and set it by calling below method from mSlidingTabLayout

```
/**
 * Set the custom {@link TabColorizer} to be used.
 *
 * If you only require simple custmisation then you can use
 * {@link #setSelectedIndicatorColors(int...)} and {@link #setDividerColors(int...)} to achieve
 * similar effects.
 */
public void setCustomTabColorizer(TabColorizer tabColorizer) {
    mTabStrip.setCustomTabColorizer(tabColorizer);
}
```

or you can just change

```
private static final int DEFAULT_SELECTED_INDICATOR_COLOR = 0xFFF49e04;
```

from **SlidingTabStrip** class.

Edited:

your main activity or any objects that you want to control the color must implement below interface:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements SlidingTabLayout.TabColorizer
```

then in the override methods select your color according to position:

```
@Override
public int getIndicatorColor(int position) {

    return (Your color value );
}


@Override
public int getDividerColor(int position) {
    return (Your color value );
}
```

Then you must pass that object to SlidingTab.

Comment: Could you give me an example? Without changing DEFAULT_SELECTED_INDICATOR_COLOR.

Comment: I'm very curious about this snippet but don't have a pc with me right now to test it out. So I'll ask you: does this TabColorizer interface implement a sort of fade between the colors or the change from one fade to another is hard?

Comment: unfortunately I can not remember whether it implements it or not but at the end I think you can use `objectAnimatore` to achieve it.